# HighCharts: automatic x-axis issue in presence of missing data values

Tags: highcharts, scatter-plot, missing-data

Consider the following [chart](http://jsfiddle.net/2rNzr/65/) toy example which contains a missing value:

```
   $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                lineWidth:1,
            }
        },
        series: [{data:[[-3.8,0.4],[-3.3,-0.2],null,[-4.9,-0.7],[-4.8,-0.3]]}]
    });
```

The points lie in the left side on the chart and don't span all its width, as it happens when you remove the missing point from the data series. In other words, the automatic min and max x-axis values seems to not be correctly computed.

In another one of my real examples the issue is more dramatic: all the data points are accumulated on a tiny strip on the left while the remainder of the chart area is completely empty.

What's wrong? It's a bug? There's a solution or a workaround?

Comment: The null value means that point does not exist, so line cannot be printed between points, where null exists. This is proper behaviour. In case when you would like to link points after null, you should add previous point like here: http://jsfiddle.net/k8jug6hy/ or remove null value from data in preprocessing.

Comment: I've inserted a null point because I do NOT want to connect points before it and point after it. Anyway I don't understand how this impact on point spanning over the chart area.

Comment: the `null` value seems to show up as a `0` in the `series.xData`, which is reflected in the `axis.dataMax`, which is how the axis extremes get selected. Weirdly it shows up as a `null` in the `series.yData`. Can't see a solution currently, but maybe someone can dig some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a null x value in Highcharts.

If you want the null point to work as you've described, you need to provide an x value in order to tell the chart where the null y value is.

You've supplied your data in `[x,y]` pairs, so you must do that for all data points, including the `null` value.

Updated example, using `[-3,null]`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/2rNzr/69/